# encrypt or disable dictionary and list output in ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible

Is it possible to encrypt or disable the output of dictionary and list output in ansible?

I'm using ansible-vault encrypted vars in a dict, by executing in play they will be shown in cleartext on output n console...

```
changed: [host1] => (item={u'key': u'test', u'value': {u'cgrouptype': u'test', u'nexususer': u'storuser', u'notstartable': u'no', u'nexuspassword': u'passwordinclear', u'nexusport': u'8171', u'nexuspath': u'path/to/image', u'graylogip': u'tcp://10.20.30.40:12345'}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `no_log: true` to the task that process sensitive data or you want to keep output of out of sight:

```yaml
- name: "Opening sesame"
  command: "opensesame {{ password }}"
  no_log: true
```

> **Protecting sensitive data with `no_log`** ([docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html))
>
> If you save Ansible output to a log, you expose any secret data in your Ansible output, such as passwords and user names. To keep sensitive values out of your logs, mark tasks that expose them with the no_log: True attribute. However, the no_log attribute does not affect debugging output, so be careful not to debug playbooks in a production environment.

Comment: no_log: true works but unfortunately when that task has an error I can't see what happens or what was the error...

Comment: Either it's sensitive data ot not. In case of error you can always enable logging back (anyone can) and debug but this does not change sensitivity of data.